# Multiplying two uint16_t numbers results in an int

Tags: c++

Take a look at the following snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <boost/type_index.hpp>
using boost::typeindex::type_id_with_cvr;
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
        constexpr uint16_t b = 2;
        constexpr uint16_t c = 3;
        constexpr const auto bc = b * c;
        std::cout << "b: " << type_id_with_cvr<decltype(b)>().pretty_name() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "b * c: " << type_id_with_cvr<decltype(bc)>().pretty_name()  << std::endl;
}
```

This results in the following:

`b: unsigned short const`

`b * c: int const`

Why does multiplying two unsinged ints results in an integer?

Compiler: g++ 5.4.0

Answer (score 3):

`unsigned short` values are implicitly converted to an `int` **before** the multiplication.

`short` and `char` are considered "storage types" and implicitly converted to `int` before doing computations. It's the reason for which

```
unsigned char x = 255, y = 1;
printf("%i\n", x+y); // you get 256, not 0
```